# PHPWORD Line numbering

Tags: php, phpword

how do I add line numbering to my document?

I added this;

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:lnNumTyp');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:start', '5');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:restart', '1');
$objWriter->endElement();
```

To my `PhpWord\Writer\Word2007\Document.php` script, immediately after;

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:sectPr');
```

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct code is as follows;

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:lnNumType');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:countBy', '5');
$objWriter->writeAttribute('w:restart', 'continuous');
$objWriter->endElement();
```

It still goes after;

```
$objWriter->startElement('w:sectPr');
```

Comment: This is working for the PHPWord version located [here](https://phpword.codeplex.com/).

Comment: can we do the same with xml attribute or mso-elements? like '<w:sectPr>'
  '<w:lnNumType w:countBy="1">'
  '</w:sectPr>'

Answer (score 2):

Use the `lineNumbering` property of `Section` style that were available since [0.10.0](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/releases/tag/0.10.0).

Example: `section = $phpWord->addSection(array('lineNumbering' => array()));`